# HTML5 Video element in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I recently upgraded a site to play all its videos using the `<video>` element.  It's a simple, static HTML site, with some minor javascript to load videos into the `<video>` element.

Everything works fine from the the file system, but once I deploy it, it works in all my test browsers except in Internet Explorer 11 with the error message

> Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path

I could understand if it didn't work in IE from the file system as well, but it's only from the web.

```
<div id="video_plate" style="width: 760px; height: 546px;">
    <video id="video1" style="width: 720px; height: 486px;" src="videos/test.m4v" controls="">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video> 
     <div id="video_title">Test</div>
     <div id="video_title2">Bob Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very strange behavior.  Just for fun, I renamed one of the m4v files to mp4.  It still didn't play, but all the m4v files started playing fine.  Going to put this down to some kind of cache issue. `when all else fails, kill the cache`

Comment: Nope. That wasn't it. Accidentally loaded the disk version in a different open IE.

Comment: Can you check the MIME type the web server returns for .m4v files? It's possible IE11 doesn't recognise this MIME type, even if it recognises the file type that Windows reports locally for the same file.

Comment: IE returns `video/mp4`, largely due to the .htaccess file on the site.

Comment: Browserstack.com shows the video playing fine in IE 11 (Windows 8), but broken in IE11 (Windows 7).  So I guess it's a Windows 7 thing.

Comment: Oh. Well, I do have a virtual machine running Windows 7 here, but that one only has IE9 on it, which says it doesn't support the video tag. Other than that, I can only confirm what you're seeing; it does play in IE11 under Windows 8.1 and also in FF under Windows 7, as well as all browsers locally under Linux. However, let's not beat around the bush, it's an ad. Maybe you have ad blocking problems?

Comment: LOL - That would be some impressive technology to determine an ad based solely on its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue with Windows 7 and IE 11.  By default, IE 11 is configured with `protected mode` ON in the Internet Options > Security settings.  This blocks videos from playing using the `video` element.  Turn `protected mode` OFF, and the video plays properly, without the vague, and less than helpful error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the level of supporting video type for Explorer 11 (and for the other brower ) with canuse  http://caniuse.com/#feat=video
In sub- features You can see also the specific type of supported video format

```
     WebM video format not supported 
     MPEG-4/H.264 video format       ** supported **
     Ogg/Theora video format not supported 
     WebVTT - Web Video Text Tracks
```

no other 
Only mpeg4 seems supported for IE11

Comment: m4v is mpeg4.  Plus, it plays fine when loaded from disk.

Comment: well then check the path., use firebugs or similar for debugger

Comment: RTQ - Works in all other browsers.